# Get ID of an element which is not accessible in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, action

On my project, I am displaying all the rows in the database of a model. However, I am doing this on the index page of another model. And I have a button associated with each row so that when clicked, it'd execute the related action on the associated model. I hope my question is clear enough.

To illustrate the problem, let's say I have two models: Teacher and Student. Every teacher has many students. And in the index page for each teacher, I display all his students as a list of rows. Now, I want to have a button for each row which will change the name of the student when clicked. It doesn't matter where I have the action. It might be in Teacher(or somewhere else). I just wanna find a way for how I will know which student is being clicked. Is it the first or second student whose button got clicked?

How can I do that?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: If you have access to the model's data, you should have the id as well. It'd help if you shared the code of the view and controller so we can see exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think giving the code would complicate it worse. Let me give an example in the question. Hope it makes it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<% students = Student.all %>
<% students.each do |student| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= student.name %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Change name', '#', onclick: 'alert("ID: "' + "#{student.id})" %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```